# Changing chunk background color in RMarkdown in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, r-markdown

How I can change chunk background color in RMarkdown in VSCode ?

[image: image of chunk]

Not work:

```
{
    "scope": [
      "meta.embedded.block.r"
    ],
    "settings": {
      "background": "#181818"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quarto** - solved this problem!
Settings → Quarto › Cells › Background:
[image]